# Dynamic Marketing List Use Query NOT working - Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am creating Dynamics Marketing List in dynamics 365 for the contacts. Then trying to use a Query where Contact's Job Title contains "Astro" and it is returning me 2 contacts in the Query as it can be seen below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUKZQ.jpg)

[enter image description here][2]

Then i click on Use Query button, but rather loading these contacts from the query, CRM is displaying all the contacts from the system.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7i8y.jpg)

I have tried using different browsers but no help, i couldn't find what is going on with the system.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: That is very strange behavior. Here are a couple thoughts: 1) try filtering on some other criteria and see what happens 2) maybe create the list with all the contacts, copy to static, then see if grooming the list there works 3) this might be worthy of a Microsoft Support ticket.

Comment: Online or onpremise?

Comment: Hi Arun, its Dynamics CRM 365 Online

Comment: Using SDK, Try to query the fetchxml stored for this specific dynamic list & start from there for any discrepancy in filter. For more - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2010/11/08/marketing-with-dynamic-list/

Comment: The query will be stored in query column of Marketing list. Here you go - https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2011/11/28/where-are-the-list-members-of-a-dynamic-marketing-list

Answer (score 0):

This may be the issue with fetchxml query stored for identifying the members.

Check the value in query column of Dynamic Marketing list record & identify the root cause of this problem.

You may need to use a SDK call if it's not readily available to check the query value in CRM online.

Refer:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2011/11/28/where-are-the-list-members-of-a-dynamic-marketing-list

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2010/11/08/marketing-with-dynamic-list/

Comment: Hi Arun, thank you for you value able answer. Somehow i have managed to copy fetch xml query to another temporary field on the form and query looks perfect, just to make sure i ran that fetch xml query using XRM tool box fetch xml tester and it brings only 4 records back as you can see in the link attached (http://i67.tinypic.com/316vhjo.jpg). However in the marketing list members there are still more than 5000+ contacts. i am thinking to raise this with Microsoft. what would you advise? thanks

Comment: Perfect, raise the issue with MS. If my answer helped you, upvote/mark it.